# Speaker connections

Tags: parallel, series

Hello and good day to all. I have a McIntosh C2500 preamp. Also 2 Klipsch 8 ohm speakers and 2 Elac 8 ohm speakers. My question is what is best wiring connection for them to this McIntosh pre amp. Series or parallel?

Comment: The C2500 is only a preamp - you would need to add a power amplifier to drive your speakers.

Answer (score 1):

A preamp is a pre-amplifier and used to condition line-level signals - typically < 1 V and impedance > 50 kΩ - by buffering them and adding tone control, etc. This is completely inadequate for driving loudspeakers.

The pre-amp should feed into a **power amplifier** which will accept the line-level signal and boost both voltage and current to drive the 8 Ω speakers. If you want stereo sound your power-amplifier will require two channels (two amplifiers), one for left and one for right.